# Gostaria dessa barra ao rolar a página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Mas só ir preenchendo as etapas ao rolar a página, alguém pode ajudar?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 1;
$('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
setInterval(function() {
$('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('active');

$('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

$('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ') .label').html('&#10003;');

$('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').addClass('active');

$('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 2) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

i++;

if (i == 0) {
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
$('.progress div.circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
i = 1;
}
}, 1000);
});
```

```css
.progress {
width: 1000px;
margin: 20px auto;
text-align: center;
}
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
display: inline-block;
background: #fff;
width: 40px; height: 40px;
border-radius: 40px;
border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
}
.progress .bar {
position: relative;
width: 80px;
height: 6px;
top: -33px;
margin-left: -5px;
margin-right: -5px;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
border-radius: 0;
}
.progress .circle .label {
display: inline-block;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
line-height: 32px;
border-radius: 32px;
margin-top: 3px;
color: #b5b5ba;
font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
color: #b5b5ba;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 30px;
margin-left: -5px;
}

/* Done / Active */
.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
color: #FFF;
background: #81CE97;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
color: #444;
}
.progress .circle.active .label {
color: #FFF;
background: #0c95be;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.progress .circle.active .title {
color: #0c95be;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
<div class="circle done">
<span class="label">1</span>
<span class="title">Titulo 1</span>
</div>
<span class="bar done"></span>
<div class="circle done">
<span class="label">2</span>
<span class="title">Titulo 2</span>
</div>
<span class="bar half"></span>
<div class="circle active">
<span class="label">3</span>
<span class="title">Titulo 3</span>
</div>
<span class="bar"></span>
<div class="circle">
<span class="label">4</span>
<span class="title">Titulo 5</span>
</div>
<span class="bar"></span>
<div class="circle">
<span class="label">5</span>
<span class="title">Titulo 6</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o seu exemplo eu fiz um outro, tem muita coisa que pode ser alterado, mas o básico está ai.

Está no [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3bbzdu88/)

Você deve usar o `$(window).on("scroll", function() { });` para conseguir "pegar" a alteração do scroll.

Com `scrollLeft()` você consegue pegar a posição do scroll.

Depois é só usar uma lógica.

Comment: Boa, agora tenho que ver se consigo no scroll down, não pros lados, mas já ajudou muito!